# What exactly does stack runghc do?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

A bit of a background that leads to the question I have.

I am learning Yesod, and I am reading the Yesod book. In the [*Basics* section of the book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics), the instructions on how to get a basic Yesod application was given. The instructions basically says put this in a file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
import           Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
```

and run it with `runhaskell helloworld.hs` or `stack runghc helloworld.hs`. I did exactly this and that did not work. I get an error about `yesod` cannot be found. Apparently there is step I should have ran prior to this, which is not mentioned in the basic section. I found that step in the quickstart guide here https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart

And the instruction in there basically says

- install stack
- Create a new scaffolded site: stack new my-project yesodweb/sqlite && cd my-project
- Install the yesod command line tool: stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc
- Build libraries: stack build
- Launch devel server: stack exec -- yesod devel
- View your Yesod site at http://localhost:3000/

I followed all of this and it seems to work, but now back to running the `helloworld.hs` file in the basic section. I understand above that the command `stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc` installs a `yesod`. So I thought that would fix the problem of `Yesod` not found. I went back to the directory where I had the `helloworld.hs` file and ran `stack runghc helloworld.hs` but that did not work.

It only worked when I moved `helloworld.hs` into the `my-project` project I created when I followed the quickstart guide. So my question now is, what exactly does the command `stack runghc helloworld.hs` and why is it that the command only works when I have the `helloworld.hs` file in a stack project?

Answer (score 2):

Think of stack projects like node packages or python virtualenvs: they have their own dependencies that are separate from whatever you installed on your system. `runhaskell` (which does not go through stack) will use your global dependencies, but you didn't have `yesod` installed globally so it complained that it wasn't found. If you `stack install yesod-bin` inside a stack project, it will install it for **that** stack project only, so you can only use the dependencies if you're inside that project. For global installations, consider using `cabal` (note that cabal is horrific at package management and will error out on half the packages you try to install, so it's better to just stick with stack).

Comment: `stack install` does not install packages "into project"